# Ajax calls vs. server side calls

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, client-side, server-side

I am building a twitter feed widget for Wordpress, and one of the issues I have to deal with is Twitter's rate limits (150 tweets per hour per account). I have noticed that when i'm fetching the tweets using server-side calls (e.g. `file_get_contents()`) the limit is reached very quickly, especially on a shared host. I've tried to fetch the tweets using client-side calls with jQuery's `getJSON` function, and the rate limit took a lot longer to reach.

- What is the reason for this difference between client-side and
  server-side calls when it comes to Twitter rate limits?
- Which method would be preferable for this case?

**Update**
I should note that the tweets are being cached to avoid hitting the rate limits, but that does not help when the calls are made from a shared host.

Comment: Sounds pretty straight forward, "Unauthenticated calls are permitted 150 requests per hour. Unauthenticated calls are measured against the public facing IP of the server or device making the request."  So if you want more than 150 an hour use the client.

Comment: Let see if I got that right - using client side calls, I will get 150 calls per user/client?

Comment: OP is asking *why* there's a difference between how quickly they hit the rate limit using the different methods.

Comment: yeah and.... calls are measured against the public facing IP of the server or device making the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use server-side calls, all the calls are coming from the same IP; all the users are sharing the same 150 tweat/hour quota.

When you use client-side calls, they calls come from different IPs for each client. Each client gets 150 tweats per hour, so all the clients combined can get a much larger volume.